# cisco sg550X support m-lag and

Tags: cisco, lacp

Please tell me

1. Support MC-LAG (Multichassis Link Aggregation Groups) model cisco sg550x?
2. can i use at the same time in stack for example:
   1/1-2/1: M-LAG (LAG1)
   and
   1/19-2/20,1/20-2/19: for stack ports in LAG2(or in stack ports LAG not needed and works automatically)

I want to buy sg550X, but dont know function support.

can look at Cisco C9300-24UX-E(M-LAG, StackWise-480)?

Answer (score 0):

The SG550x will support mLAG:

From the [datasheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/550x-series-stackable-managed-switches/datasheet-c78-735874.html):

> Support for IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregation Control Protocol (LACP)
>
> ●  Up to 32 groups
>
> ●  Up to 8 ports per group with 16 candidate ports
> for each (dynamic) 802.3ad LAG

Answer (score 0):

no, they don't support MC-LAG.

- you can "stack" up to 8 devices using (550XG at least) using standard network (SFP+)Ports, even with "LAG"-(Etherchannel-like)-redundant connections between stack-members
- but this is no real "MC-LAG" where multiple Controle-Planes would be active! Within this SG-550XG-Stack, there is one Active-Unit(former "Master"), one Standby-Unit(former "Backup") and than "Member"-Units(former "Slave")
- so a "MC-LAG" physical Topology is possible, but no MC-LAG-Style "active-active"-Control-Planes limiting overall availability

The MC-LAG is available in the Cisco Nexus product line and called VPC, virtual port channel.

An entry switch with VPC/MC-LAG would be Cisco Nexus 3524-X for example.